# Searching through form & Uses

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

We are creating a component and want to mimic the concept behind Designer.GetComponentNames, where as we give can obtain a list of the available components on the form or any form in the uses. We haven't been able to get to the root of GetComponentNames. Any input would be much appreciated.

LE: Actually I take that back. I need this from the design time aspect.

Comment: Voted to close as not a real Q. You ask for an equivalent to GetComponentNames at design time. That's a non sequiter.

Answer (score 1):

Runtime? You have the Vcl.Forms.TScreen.Forms array for all the displayed forms, and you have Vcl.Forms.Application.Components containing all your forms IIRC. Then, each form has a Components array.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the first part of your question, you want to get a list of components owned by a form (by name) at designtime.

As background, I have a non-visual component (Call it TColorEdits.) that manages the colors of selected TWinControls on a form at runtime. This component has a TStrings property that contains the names of selected TWinControls on the form. The names of TWinControls to be managed may be selected at designtime using a dialog (dlgEditColors) that contains a couple listboxes, one of which is named DstList and shows all TWinControls available for management by TColorEdits.

So, here is some (simplified) code I use to get the names of TWinControls on a form at designtime and load the TWinControl names into DstList.

```
   { Load names of TWinControls owned by a form into TListBox DstList }
    for i := 0 to TColorEdits(GetComponent(0)).Owner.ComponentCount - 1 do
      if ((TColorEdits(GetComponent(0)).Owner.Components[i] is TWinControl) then
        dlgEditColors.DstList.Items.Add(TColorEdits(GetComponent(0)).Owner.Components[i].Name);
```

You should be able to adjust the above code as part of a custom property editor for your component. Hope this helps with the first part of your question.